# Use multiple return statement

Tags: optimization, return

Is there a considerable difference of optimization between these two codes (in Java and/or C++, currently, even if I guess it's the same in every languages) ? Or is it just a question of code readability ?

```
int foo(...) {
    if (cond) {
        if (otherCondA)
            return 1;
        if (otherCondB)
            return 2;
        return 3;
    }
    int temp = /* context and/or param-dependent */;
    if (otherCondA)
        return 4 * temp;
    if (otherCondB)
        return 4 / temp;
    return 4 % temp;
}
```

and

```
int foo(...) {
    int value = 0;
    if (cond) {
        if (otherCondA)
            value = 1;
        else if (otherCondB)
            value = 2;
        else value = 3;
    }
    else {
        int temp = /* context and/or param-dependent */;
        if (otherCondA)
            value = 4 * temp;
        else if (otherCondB)
            value = 4 / temp;
        else
            value = 4 % temp;
    }
    return value;
}
```

The first one is shorter, avoid multiple imbrications of else statement and economize one variable (or at least seems to do so), but I'm not sure that it really changes something...

Comment: You're not sure it's a good idea... why? Do you have any *rational* reasons or did you just wake up this morning feeling that way? Have you tried to inspect the generated code or to use profiling tools?

Comment: Many people advocate a single `return` because they think the code is easier to reason through. Even when I follow that advice I also allow early returns at the front of the function when preconditions fail.

Comment: After a few tests, the compiler can only optimise the kind of multiple return statement which MarkRansom talks about. In the middle of a function, the optimisation is very poor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking deeper into the different assembly codes generated by GCC, here's the results :

The multiple return statement is more efficient during "normal" compilation, but with the -O_ flag, the balance change :

The more you optimise the code, the less the first approach worths. It makes the code harder to optimise, so, use it carefully. As said in comments, it's very powerful when used at the front of the function when testing preconditions, but in the middle of the function, it's a nightmare for the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Of course the multiple return is acceptable.
Because you can halt the program as soon as the function is finished